# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Deployed application is available in all Worklight Consoles

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have installed IBM Worklight Server 6.0 in WAS 8.0.

I have deployed a projectA.war & projectB.war via ant script and I can access both the console with the different context root.

The problem I am facing here is, I have deployed the appA.wlapp in projectA.war via the Worklight console, the same application is available when I access the projectB.war console.

Can anyone help me to find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only guess right now is that there is a mutual database for both projects so you see the same app in both consoles (and that too only happens w/out an error because maybe the different .war files have identical authenticationConfig.xml settings).

That is, the same database configuration is used for both projects; This configuration is either:

- Part of the .war files that you deploy (in worklight.properties), or
- Something that you configure in the Ant task script used to deploy the .war files, or
- Some configuration in the application server hosting the .war files.

See documentation: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Fc_clustering.html

Comment: Yeah, I have Mysql DB which is running on port 3306. But the projectA.war is simple HelloWorld and projectB.war contains an custom authentication but both has default worklight.properties values. Both war files were configured to use same database.

Comment: Well, this explains it then... if both of them access the same database, you will see the app in both consoles.

Comment: Do you mean that every .war file should point separate databases? If this the scenario, I want to have 2 .war files which can host different set of applications[different authentication as well]. Then Should I have 2 DB's?

Comment: Can you help me to understand why worklight works in this way?

Comment: What is there not to understand? You are pointing both projects to the same database, the database holds all deployed applications, the console displays all deployed applications, thus both consoles display the same application, because both are looking at the same database; If you want two projects that have completely different security settings and applications, use different databases for each. Depending on the database you choose to use (Oracle, MySQL, DB2) different approaches can be taken. I cannot list here all possible options. You asked why the same app is in both consoles, answered.

Comment: In the case of DB2 or Oracle, starting with Worklight 6.0, you can also have the two .war files refer to *different* schemas in the *same* database. This works just like two different databases, but reduces the load on the database server. Refer to the documentation of <configureDatabase> and <configureApplicationSever> for how to declare the schema to be used for each.